# how can i get a resultcode when i use 'startActivity' to install an apk

Tags: android

I installed an apk which was saved in directory of `/data/data/package_name/files` with codes below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(apkSavingPath));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

I want it to return a resultcode to tell me whether the apk installed successfully or not, and  I have tried method of `startActivityForResult`, but it didn't work.

On method of `onActivityResult`, it's resultCode is always `0(zero)` whether apk installed successfully or not. Can I get such a resultcode?

Comment: The simple answer is "you cannot".  Installer activity doesn't return any result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install APK programmatically on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362479/install-apk-programmatically-on-android)

Answer (score 5):

try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);           
intent.setDataAndType("ApkFilePath...","application/vnd.android.package-archive");
activity.startActivityForResult(intent,5000);
```

Add your receiver on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This class then gets called when a new package is installed:

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // handle install event here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But after adding `android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"`. I edited your answer.